# проверка происходит раньше чем переменная получает значения

Tags: java, android

У меня есть код,

```
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            telefonnumer.setText("");
            TvDitalicHotel.setText("");
            tvOfSait.setText("");


            imgurl.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(DitalicHotelModel.class).getImg());
            TvDitalicHotel.setText( dataSnapshot.getValue(DitalicHotelModel.class).toString());
            telefonnumer.setText( dataSnapshot.getValue(DitalicHotelModel.class).Telephone());
            tvOfSait.setText( dataSnapshot.getValue(DitalicHotelModel.class).openSait());



        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(HotelViewActivity.this, "нет информации", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
    Picasso.with(this).load("" + imgurl.getText()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(app_view_Hotel);
```

Но проверка происходит раньше, чем переменная(imgurl) получает значения. Как это исправить?

Comment: Боюсь предположить конечно.. но мб достаточно будет сделать проверку после получения значения?

Comment: @Artilirium так оно и расположено в коде

Comment: может быть тогда код покажете? А то это гадание на чаинках :)

Comment: @Artilirium нет возможности

Comment: тогда у нас не будет возможности Вам помочь, вариантов правда множество :)

Comment: @VTeme Я тоже предположу... А запись значения происходит в другом потоке?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov это как ?

Comment: @VTeme значит нет :)

Comment: @Artilirium дополнил вопрос

Comment: @V Teme А теперь напечатайте этот код нормально в специальном блоке, а не в повернутой картинке с непонятным почерком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну чтож, предположительно вы получаете данные с помощью некоего `Listener`-а, в блоке кода, который исполняется в любом случае после метода `onCreate`, а стало быть Вам надо перенести проверку (или же само исполнение) в тот же блок кода `Listener`-a.

Иначе у Вас так и будет сначала проходить проверка, а потом присвоение :)

**UPD**: Ввиду появления новой неконкретной информации, гадаем дальше:

Вы попытались засунуть блок кода

```
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imag‌​eView1);
```

внутрь некоего `Listener`-a и получили неожиданную ошибку..

Возможно всё действо происходит внутри `Activity`, с кодовым-предположительным названием `MainActivity`, тогда Вам следует этот блок кода снова вернуть в `Listener` с маленьким изменением:

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imag‌​eView1);
```

где кодовое название `MainActivity` меняете на своё суперсекретное :)

Comment: Я думал об этом , но выдают ошибку , я использую Picasso . Он не хочет туда , Picasso.with(context).

Comment: Ну наконец-то долгожданные подробности :)
Вы в Picasso используете метод .fetch(new Callback... ) ?

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);

Comment: обновил ответ :)

Comment: Да все верно,  как только проверю поставлю вам галочку , и плюсик вам к карме